# Magento 2 backend error

Tags: magento2, admin, error, xml, backend

Got this problem after installing new module using composer. Module has been removed already but error still is present. 
This error appears only after trying to log into backend. Frontend as well as backend login screen works as intended. Magento 2 system.log shows the same error, not sure how to debug this.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /var/www/portostock/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 386

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /var/www/portostock/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 386
<pre>#1 DOMDocument->loadXML('') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:386]
#2 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:147]
#3 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->merge('') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:151]
#4 Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(&Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator#000000003ab0cbec000000007a29194d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:130]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('adminhtml') called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:144]
#6 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->_initMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:111]
#7 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:364]
#8 Magento\Backend\Model\Url->_getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:324]
#9 Magento\Backend\Model\Url->getStartupPageUrl() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Url/Interceptor.php:102]
#10 Magento\Backend\Model\Url\Interceptor->getStartupPageUrl() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:282]
#11 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->_processUrlKeys() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/Index/Interceptor.php:50]
#12 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\Index\Interceptor->_processUrlKeys() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:208]
#13 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#14 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#15 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#16 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\Index\Interceptor#000000003ab0ccab000000007a29194d#, &Closure#000000003ab0ccad000000007a29194d#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#17 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#19 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:55]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab0cf67000000007a29194d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:257]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000003ab0cf16000000007a29194d#) called at [pub/index.php:37]
</pre>
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run all deployment commands after uninstalling vendor module ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya if you mean setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile then yes. Cleaned all the cache and manually deleted generated, view_preprecessed,cache and page_cache folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your module folder or within your magento root directory there would be an empty xml fie just delete it and run `setup:static-content:deploy -f` and clear your cache.
hope this will solve your issue.

After this run run deploy command for static content

Comment: Thank you so much! It really was an 0 size file not related to the module I installed today. Not sure how that happened but when I replaced the file everthing started to work.
Used this command: find "$dir" -size 0 -name "*.xml" -type f

Comment: if you find  my ans helpful please accept it as  an ans!

Comment: Already did, however cannot rank it up because of low level.